# Hiveserver2 Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos

If I want to configure my HiveServer2 (we use selfmade hadoop enviroment) to use Kerberos authentication it's require a secure hadoop envoriment too?

What I mean:

after I installed the kerberos I want to secure my Hiveserver2, but first I have to secure my hdfs, hadoop core-conf, mapred etc.. or not?

I hope it make sense, thank your for the help!

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Server configuration belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: You can find more guide in google. If you are getting any error while configuring securing Hadoop then you can ask here.

Comment: When I try to start the hiveserver2: (hive.log)
2015-06-19 13:32:58,825 ERROR [Thread-7]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:run(101)) - Error starting HiveServer2: could not start ThriftBinaryCLIService
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Kerberos principal should have 3 parts: root

Maybe could you tell me which are these 3 parts?

Answer (score 0):

In order to kerborize hive server 2, It is must to kerborize all other hadoop services(for example hdfs, yarn etc) as well.
I don't know what is the meaning of selfmade hadoop environment. You better use cloudera manager(CDH) or ambari server(Hortonworks) to enable kerberos for your hadoop services.